# CACert.org certificate giving sec_error_unknown_issuer

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I have used cacert.org to issue class 1 certificates for my website. I made sure that the subdomain name is correct and that the e-mail address is there, but yet I keep getting the certificate problem with Firefox and other browsers:

```
sec_error_untrusted_issuer
```

I tried [this tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxCertManagement) but it didn't fix the problem.

My apache configuration is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /path/to/web
ServerName blog.mydomain.com
<Directory "/path/to/web">
    <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
        php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile      /home/myhome/SSL/CACert/cert_signed.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /home/myhome/SSL/CACert/privkey.pem
SSLCipherSuite HIGH
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2

</VirtualHost>
```

I don't even know where to start to fix this. Please assist.

Thank you for any efforts.

Comment: You forgot to install the chain certificate.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm sorry it was the wrong message. I corrected it.

Comment: Did you try installing the chain certificate(s)?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I did, and I changed the error message to the new one.

Comment: [Read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAcert.org#Inclusion_status)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thank you... this is so disappointing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by going to another certificate authority.

CAcert.org certificates are [*not* recognized by the most common browsers](http://wiki.cacert.org/InclusionStatus).